# How to make a copy of related field in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

fields is a list of EavAttribute name likes `['a', 'b', 'c']`

fields_order is a list of EavAttribute order likes [1,2,3] , `foreign keys` is same with fields.

I want to make a copy of fields to `serializer` an order field list.

```py
class EavForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class EavAttribute(models.Model):
    form = models.ForeignKey(EavForm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fields')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class EavFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fields = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True,read_only=True,slug_field='name')

    # not work here ,how to fix 
    fields_order = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True,read_only=True,slug_field='order')

    class Meta:
        model = EavForm
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a  `Serializermethodfield`

```
class EavFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fields = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True,read_only=True,slug_field='name')


    fields_order = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_field_order(self, obj):
        return obj.fields.all()
```